# Help with Recursive SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2000

I have a category table similar to this:

```
   uid | ParentLevel | ParentID | Name
   ------------------------------------
    1  |       0     |      0   |  foo
    2  |       1     |      1   |  blat
    3  |       1     |      1   |  baz
    4  |       2     |      3   |  blah
    5  |       0     |      0   |  bar
```

I am trying to get output similar to this:

```
1 | foo
2 | foo | blat
3 | foo | baz
4 | foo | baz | blah
5 | bar
```

And so on. CTE's are out as this is SQL 2000.  I have tried something like this, but can't seem to get it quite right:

```
SELECT     c1.uid, c1.Name, c2.Name AS Expr1, c3.Name AS Expr2
FROM         dbo.Categories AS c1 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Categories AS c2 ON c1.uid = c2.ParentID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Categories AS c3 ON c2.uid = c3.ParentID
WHERE     (c1.ParentLevel = 0) AND (c2.ParentLevel = 1) AND (c3.ParentLevel = 2)
```

This would only return records if there is a third level which isn't always true. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and move conditions on level from `WHERE` to `JOIN` conditions

```
SELECT      c1.uid, c1.Name, c2.Name AS Expr1, c3.Name AS Expr2
FROM        dbo.Categories AS c1 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Categories AS c2 
        ON  c1.uid = c2.ParentID
        AND c2.ParentLevel = 1
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Categories AS c3 
        ON  c2.uid = c3.ParentID
        AND c3.ParentLevel = 2
WHERE       c1.ParentLevel = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT     c1.uid, c1.Name, c2.Name AS Expr1, c3.Name AS Expr2
FROM         dbo.Categories AS c1 LEFT JOIN 
                  dbo.Categories AS c2 ON c1.uid = c2.ParentID LEFT JOIN 
                  dbo.Categories AS c3 ON c2.uid = c3.ParentID
WHERE     (c1.ParentLevel = 0) AND (c2.ParentLevel = 1) AND (c3.ParentLevel = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN will help you to get the expected result. INNER JOIN merges only the records which matches from other query result.